# Google Sheets - Automatically Add Last Date Updated, but to a different cell for each tab

Tags: google-sheets, scripting, tabs

Looking to add the last edited date by tab, and have found others with scripts like:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (ss.getName()=='Tab 1'){
    ss.getRange('F3').setValue(new Date())
  }
}
```

But, due to wonky reasons, the sheets document I'm working on does not have a consistent location for the cell I want to set the Date value. On Tab 1, It's F3, but on Tab 2, it could be L4.

When I try stacking additional if statements, it adds the date value to all of the locations in the entire script, and when I try breaking them out into different .gs modules, it only ever takes the most recent one.

Is there any way to get it to paste into a specific cell for each tab? I recognize it would be easiest to update the underlying document to be consistent, but there are some other dependencies that make that harder than it sounds to implement. Thanks in advance for any insights!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, my coworker may have have found an answer -

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if(ss.getName()=='Sheet 1') {e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet 1")
    ss.getRange("A1").setValue(new Date())}
  if(ss.getName()=='Sheet 2') {e.source.getSheetByName("Sheet 2")
    ss.getRange("A2").setValue(new Date())}
}
```